# What were Jury consideration when convicting Bill Cosby?

Tags: rape

http://time.com/3951761/bill-cosby-quaaludes-admission-oath/

Bill says he gives quaaludes to girls before having sex with them

This leads to a lot of "problems"

1. Is the quaaludes consensual?
2. Do girls are "in control" when they got qualudes? I mean will the girl be knocked out sleepy or just "horny"
3. Did the girl actually testify that she didn't know she is getting qualudes?

In Indonesia, it's pretty common to get girls really drunk and have sex. The girls know all along that's going to happen.

The fact that you're drunk doesn't mean that you can't make up your mind.

So I wonder what's wrong with Bill?

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, we treat the use of drugs as a way to impair someone's ability to give or withhold consent to sex. In the absence of consent, sex is rape.

Comment: In other word, even if the girl knows she is taking Quaalude, even if the girl get drunk con sensually, and even if she can simply say no, it's still rape. I.e. Getting a girl so turned on by aphrosidiac is rape

Comment: Basically I would like an answer that elaborate on the distinction. After all why would Bill, a very rich man, want to risk raping a girl that can simply report?

Comment: Why would *any* man rape a woman who could report?

Comment: poor man? Men with nothing to lose? Men that can't get girls.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misconceptions about why men rape women.

Comment: No. I think you do. Saying that rape is not about sex is like saying that robbing bank is not about money. Men that rapes are usually poor.

Comment: Rape is not about sex, it's about power and control and entitlement. Rape is committed as often by the rich and the middle-class, as the poor. Your very question itself demonstrates a naiveté about rape.